# svn merge starts at different revs

Tags: svn, merge

I have a project(Foo) and a branch(Bar) that needs to be brought up to date from trunk.  If svn merge is run at the top level it starts the merge from 197894, but a merge while inside that subdir starts at 204284 which is preferred.

i.e.:

```
$> svn merge URL:/trunk .
```

----> Lots 'o conflicts when it gets to Baz
meanwhile:

```
$> cd Baz
$> svn merge URL:/branch/Bar/Baz .
```

---> Nice!

Is there a way to repair or tell the mergeinfo props that it's current rev is where to start merges (esp. when it's started from top level directory).

Note that in an attempt to get this to work, the subdir was recreated from trunk via svn delete/svn copy. Perhaps some of the mergeinfo is lost/confusing?  However the thought was that this would make it up to date wrt trunk.

here's what svn tells me:

## trunk ...

```
svn info https://corp.com/svn/Foo/trunk/Baz
Last Changed Rev: 204286
svn propget svn:mergeinfo https://corp.com/svn/Foo/trunk/Baz
/Foo/trunk/Baz:197626-197892
```

## branch ...

```
svn info https://corp.com/svn/Foo/branch/Bar/Baz
Last Changed Rev: 204284      # 2 behind trunk
svn propget svn:mergeinfo https://corp.com/svn/Foo/branch/Bar
/Foo/trunk:197297-204098
svn propget svn:mergeinfo https://corp.com/svn/Foo/branch/Bar/Baz
/Foo/trunk/Baz:197626-197892   # this looks suspicious !?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svn info https://corp.com/svn/Foo/branch/Bar/Baz
Last Changed Rev: 204284      # 2 behind trunk
```

I suspect `svn info` is reporting the last revision that included a change to the Baz branch. Remember revision numbers are repository wide and not per branch. A similar thing is probably happening with the other branches.